# Java - How to accomplish partial updating of an entity from a map or JsonObject?

Tags: java, entity, jax-rs, updates

I'm using jax-rs in my project, I use @POST for partial update which consumes json.

my code is something like this:

```
@Path("{id}")
@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response edit(@PathParam("id") long id, Map map /*or a JsonObject*/) {
    Product product = productService.getById(id);

    if (map.containsKey("name")) {
        product.setName(String.valueOf(map.get("name")));
    }
    if (map.containsKey("description")) {
        product.setDescription(String.valueOf(map.get("description")));
    }

    // ....

    product = productService.save(product);
    return Response.ok(product, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).build();
}
```

But this does not look elegant, and it gets cumbersome as the number of attributes increases.
so, I tried to automate this mapping using apache beanutils:

```
BeanUtils.populate(product, map);
```

But what if I want to filter some attributes which should not be changed, for example the request might try to change the id by sending { id: 666 }. 

Or what if I want to do something with the values before setting the attributes, for example the json might contains a string which should be converted to Date first.

What are your solutions? are there any known practices for this problem? or is there any lib or framework which tackles this problem?

BTW, I'm trying to avoid using DTOs, and if I use dtos the question still remains.

Thank You.